# Pickup sentences between two string by regular expression in iOS

Tags: regex, regular-language

I have the following sentence:

> distributed over a considerable extent; "far-flung trading
>   operations"; "the West's far-flung mountain ranges"; "widespread
>   nuclear fallout"

What I want is to pickup the sentence between "**********";

My regular expression is ***\"(.+)"***, but the result is not what I want(only 1 match)

[image]

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked before several times. make a search on your favorite search engine, or in SO questions, you will find the answer. However, reading a regex tutorial is the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: Please be sure to read our [Help] about our voting system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will work.

```
 /\"(.+?)\"/g
```

I'm not sure that you need to escape quotes so this maybe just fine too.

```
 /"(.+?)"/g
```

Comment: Yes, it works. The **\ "[\S\s]*?"** works too. Thanks

Comment: Good. Just bear in mind `\ "[\S\s]*?"` is less specific and may result in unintended matched.

Comment: it's better to use this `"([^"]*)"`